# Create SCD type 2 table from change log table using SQL

Tags: mysql-5.6, slowly-changing-dimension

I have a change log table, which captures the transition of a state with its time, for example:

```
user_id,user_status_from,user_status_to,  created_date
 7cc4d      A2               A1       2019-11-03 23:04:26
 7cc4d      A1               A6       2019-11-03 23:05:28
 7cc4d      A6               I4       2019-11-16 10:00:34
 7cc4d      I4               A1       2020-03-16 10:00:36
```

Basically this table records the transition from one status to another, here it says that transition from 
**A2--> A1 occurred at 2019-11-03 23:04:26** (1st row) and then it moved from 
**A1 --> A6 at 2019-11-03 23:05:28** and so on.

Now I want to write a SQL through which I should be able to create table in such a way that tells the history of any status, for example: in particular status user was from this date to that date, basically a life of any status, I want to create a table like below:

```
   userId status statrtingdatetime  endingdatetime
   7cc4d   A1   2019-11-03 23:04:26 2019-11-03 23:05:28
   7cc4d   A6   2019-11-03 23:05:28 2019-11-16 10:00:34
   7cc4d   I4   2019-11-16 10:00:34 2020-03-16 10:00:36
   7cc4d   A1   2020-03-16 10:00:36 2020-04-02 08:24:50
```

If you see this table, it is nothing but some sort of logical table from above table, it says that a particular status life was from one date to another.
How can write SQL to create this final table.(please note that **LAG/LEAD** function doesn't work in my version of MySql Server)